# An efficient data structure for access by ID and finding the weighted random item

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, data-structures

Could you, please, help me with the data structure that allows `O(logN)` (or at least `O(sqrtN)`) operations for the following:

1. Insert an item having `ID` (`int64_t`) and `health` (`double`)
2. Remove an item by `ID`
3. Find an item that is weighted random by `health`

The preferred language is C++ or C. By the weighted random I mean the following:

Consider `totalHealth=Sum(health[0], health[1], ..., health[N-1])`. I need a fast (as described above) operation that is equivalent to:

1. Compute `const double atHealth = rand_uint64_t()*totalHealth/numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();`
2. Iterate over `i=0 to N-1` to find the first `i` such that `Sum(health[0], health[1], ..., health[i]) >= atHealth`

Constraints: `health[i] > 0`, `rand_uint64_t()` returns a uniformly distributed integer value between `0` and `numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max()`.

What I have tried so far is a C++ `unordered_map` that allows quick (`Θ(1)`) insertion by `ID` and removal by `ID`, but the operation #3 is still linear in `N` as described in my pseudo-code above.

You help is very appreciated!

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, you want a data structure for a fast **quantile function**(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) ? The only difference being that your distribution is unnormalized.

Comment: If you're searching you're gonna need a structure that is ordered, did you try `map`? If you don't like the stl containers, there is also https://abseil.io/docs/cpp/guides/container these ones.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann, I'm not sure either (not very familiar with the probability theory), but the `health` values aren't normalized definitely: they don't sum up to 1 and I think their normalization would be an extra operation that is also heavy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of a way to do it with the existing STL containers but I can think of a way to do it if you're willing to code up your own binary tree. The trick is that each node maintains the total health of all the nodes to its left (it doesn't need to worry about nodes to its right as you'll see below). Then, if you walk the tree in ID order you can also compute the "cumulative health", also in ID order, in `log(n)` time. So the tree is sorted by both ID and cumulative health and you can do lookups in `log(n)` time either by ID or by "cumulative health". For example, consider a very simple tree like the following:

```
         ID: 8
         h: 10
         chl: 15
   +-------|--------+
   |                |
   ID: 4          ID: 10
   h: 15          h: 7
   chl: 0         chl: 0
```

in the above `h` is the health of the node and `chl` is the cumulative health of all nodes to it's left. So the total health of all nodes in the above is 15 + 10 + 7 = 32 (and I assume you maintain that count separately though you could also track cumulative health of nodes the right and you wouldn't need to). Let's look at 3 cases:

1. You compute an `atHealth < 15`. Then at the first node you can see that your value is less than the `chl` so you know you need to go left and you end up at the correct leaf.
2. You compute an `atHealth >= 15 < 25` so you know it's > 15 so you don't go left at the root, the node you're at has health 10 and 10 + 15 means the cumulative health at that node is between 15 and 25 so you're good.
3. You compute an `atHealth >= 25`. Every time you visit a node and go right you must add the `chl` and `h` of the node you were at to keep computing cumulative health as you walk the tree so you know you're starting at `10 + 25 = 25` when you go right and you'll add that to the `h` or `chl` of any node you encounter after that. Thus you can quickly find that the node to the right is the correct one.

When you insert a new node you increment the total health of each parent node as you walk the tree and when you remove a node you walk back up the tree subtracting from the total health. Inserts and deletions are thus still `O(log(n))` and lookups by ID are also `log(n)` either by ID or by `atHealth`.

Things obviously get more complicated if you want to maintain a balanced tree but it's still do-able.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So instead of "each node maintains the total health of all the nodes to its left", do you mean that the node maintains the total health of its left subtree? Because in your example of 3 nodes it looks like that, and later in the description of the insertion operation it seems you only update the affected subtrees.

Comment: Then upon insertion and deletion, you don't increment/decrement the total health of each parent node, but rather just the parent nodes to whom you get from the left subtree.

Comment: yes, each nodes maintains the total health of its left subtree. And yes, you only need to update the relevant nodes when you insert or delete. For example, for insertion at each node if you go left you first increment the total health of the node by the node-to-be-inserted's health but if you go right you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea! I've implemented something similar: just for an easier rebalancing of an AVL tree, I maintain the total `subtreeHealth` in each node, rather than just the left subtree. It doesn't change much, just where the `subtreeHealth` of a subtree is stored: in its parent or grandparent node. So your idea is already in production :)